# Blocking error after updating an emberJS app to ember-cli and data 3.28

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

I have updated an app to ember 3.28

After managing to serve the app there is an error and a white page in the browser when I try to run the app.

This is the console error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ember._Backburner is not a constructor
    <anonymous> Ember
    exports loader.js:106
    _reify loader.js:143
    reify loader.js:130
    exports loader.js:104
    _reify loader.js:143
    reify loader.js:130
    exports loader.js:104
    _reify loader.js:143
    reify loader.js:130
    exports loader.js:104
    requireModule loader.js:27
    r loader.js:176
    Ember 3
    <anonymous> app.js:26
    exports loader.js:106
    requireModule loader.js:27
    <anonymous> Ember
```

It seems to refer to the following code :

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.28.0/packages/store/addon/-private/system/backburner.js

How can I solve or debug this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a log of time debugging this issue. The problem was a missing package `ember-export-application-global`

For me `yarn add -D ember-export-application-global` fixed everything.